# SQL collating two tables, will it permanently change the collation?

Tags: sql-server, collation

for example, i'm trying to join the product sales table with the customer info table on two different databases of the same server and i end up getting the "Cannot resolve the collation conflict between Latin1_General_CI_AS... " error...
so i've been reading up about how collate DATABASE_DEFAULT will make the uniqueidentifier columns on two tables match and join together...but is the change temporary (during the query only) or will it actually alter the collation on the 2 tables?
thanks

```
SELECT V.PRODUCT, V.DESCRIPTION, A.NAMECUST, A.NAMECITY   
FROM Warehouse.dbo.v AS V   
INNER JOIN Maindata.dbo.Customerdata AS A   
ON V.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = A.CUSTOMER_NUMBER COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

Comment: `uniqueidentifier` is a GUID and is unaffected by collation because it's a binary type. I'm guessing that one of your `CUSTOMER_NUMBER` columns is not actually a `uniqueidentifier` column?

Comment: correct...thanks man

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When `COLLATE` is used in a query (not a `CREATE/ALTER TABLE`, `CREATE/ALTER INDEX` statement) it overrides the table-table (or database-default) collation with one used just for that query, it's saying "use this collation (comparison algorithm) when comparing values for this query only". It does not affect the underlying representation of data on disk or change any definitions (that's what `ALTER` is for).

Note that using `COLLATE` in a query is often a bad code-smell: if your database is designed with correct collation in the first place then this won't be necessary.